# Partition mesh into predetermined submeshes

Tags: python, unstructured-mesh, domain-decomposition, partitioning

I have a mesh already partitioned into disjoint groups of cells. What I want to achieve is the following.

1. Obtain the adjacency graph for the cell groups.
2. Partition the mesh, i.e. generate submeshes from the cell groups in such a way that cells among the interfaces (boundaries of the cell groups) are no longer connected. This leads to new node numbers.

Notes:

1. I do not need to know to adjacency graph of the mesh cells, rather the adjacency of the cell groups.
2. Ideally, I am looking for ready software solutions, so that I don't need to reinvent the wheel.
3. Python solutions are preferred.
4. I work in two spatial dimensions with a single cell type (either fully triangular or fully quadrilateral).
5. Efficiency is not my primary concern.
6. Typically, in my application, the number of cells is at most 100k, while the number of cell groups is about 250.

Comment: Have you tried Metis?

Comment: @AloneProgrammer I considered METIS but, as far as I know, it will partition the mesh automatically or based on some *hints*, while I want the exact partitions given by the groups of cells.

Comment: So just for clarity: you mean you have the cuts and you want to just extract the partitioned mesh based on your given cuts (i.e. given groups of cells)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want (2nd requirement in my post). But I would also like to establish the connectivity of the groups (1st requirement in my post) if possible.

Comment: The hard part (the mesh partitioning) is already done. Frankly, you're asking for help on the easy part, although this type of bookkeeping coding can be tedious. I wouldn't consider it "reinventing the wheel" as much as just another part of the day-to-day unglamorous work that many of us do. What you're trying to do looks rather mundane, but custom enough that it seems unlikely to me that you would find that exact functionality in an existing library. Even if you did find what you needed, it might take longer to port your data structures to the library's data structures than to just implement

Comment: > although this type of bookkeeping coding can be tedious

Exactly. That's why I thought maybe there are existing solutions to it so that I don't have to deal with efficient data structures and algorithms.

> it might take longer to port your data structures to the library's data structures than to just implement it yourself

Yes, I thought of that. And that library could introduce hard to satisfy dependencies.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth In my opinion, OP is asking for either a software package or someone to write Python code for them to do something that I consider trivial. When I posted this, it had been 12 hours since the question was posted with no other answers. I considered saying something terser in a comment, but in the spirit of SE I didn't want to post an answer in the comments.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer The only answer that's really going to be an answer is to simply write some Python code for OP. I thought about doing that (and I might still because it's a fun problem), but I was hesitant because to my understanding this site isn't intended to be a code-writing service. Honest question -- Do you think such an answer would be appropriate here?

Comment: @LedHead I don't think OP asked for someone to write a code for him/her. The problem with your answer is that the language you used here is somewhat **unusual**. This could be a comment probably but still the language needs to be edited to become more friendly. By the way, "in the spirit of SE I didn't want to post an answer in the comments." I think this is the case where exactly it should be posted as a **comment** not an answer.

Comment: Indeed, I was not asking someone to write the code for me. I wanted to get suggestions whether this type of problem has already been solved. If so, I would not waste my time on coming up with a solution, which would most probably be suboptimal and would only steal time from the research work I really need to solve. As Prof. Bangerth pointed out in one of his lectures, it is fine to get your hands dirty with coding in the beginning (which I did during the PhD), but later one should turn to existing, robust solutions.

Comment: I disagree with the moderator's decision to delete my answer and move it to these comments. I posted a [relevant question](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/591/why-was-my-answer-deleted) on meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, constructing the adjacency graph of the "partitions" (what you call "cell groups"): Let's say you have an array $p_K$ in which you store for each cell $K$ which partition $p$ it belongs to. Also assume that you have a (sparse) array $a_{KL}$ whose entries are `true` if cells $K$ and $L$ are neighbors ("adjacent"). Then partition $s$ is "adjacent" to partition $t$ if $t$ is in the set
$$
 \left(  \bigcup_{K, p_K=s} \; \bigcup_{L, a_{KL}=\text{true}} \left\{p_L\right\} \right)\setminus \{s\}.
$$
(In other words, we loop over all cells $K$ in partition $s$, then over all neighbors $L$ of these $K$, and collect their partition indices. This union contains all partition indices that partition $s$ is adjacent to, but will likely include $s$ itself -- so we throw away $s$ at the end.

For your second question, visualization -- this is typically done in the following way:

- For each partition $s$, compute its center of mass $\mathbf x_s$, for example by taking the average of the centers of the cells in this partition.
- Compute the center of mass of the entire domain $\mathbf {\hat x}$, for example by taking the average of the centers of *all* cells.
- When visualizing the mesh, you draw each triangle with an offset $\alpha (\mathbf x_s - \mathbf {\hat x})$ with a small $\alpha$ -- say, $\alpha=0.05$. In essence, what this does is move each partition outward from the global center of mass by a distance that is proportional to how far that partition already is from the center of mass. Some visualization programs can already do that for you -- the option is typically called "explode".

Comment: I don't think the second question is about visualization, it's just about renumbering the tri/quad connectivity information.

Comment: I'm really not trying to start a fight here, but I don't think this answers the question any better than my answer. OP is asking for help with some mesh processing, and simply expressing the problem in math formalism seems unlikely to help.

Comment: As for my second question: I am not concerned about visualization (sorry for the misnomer "explode", which is used in the context of visualization), but -- as LedHead noted -- I would simply like the renumbering of the nodes. I edited my question accordingly. Nevertheless, thank you for the mesh "explode" algorithm.

Comment: I understood your algorithm. However, in order to obtain the sparse connectivity matrix $a_{KL}$, one has to create the connectivity graph of the whole mesh (in my case, the mesh is given by the cell-vertex matrix and the vertex-coordinate matrix). I think, this will be the costly part of the algorithm. At least third-party libraries can perform this task.

Comment: @ZoltánCsáti Ah, I see now how I misunderstood the "explode" part. As for $a_{KL}$: The cell-vertex matrix is what you need for that, along with its transpose. In fact, if $b_{Kv}$ is a 1-0 matrix that corresponds to which vertices $v$ are parts of cells $K$, then I believe that $a_{KL} = \sum_v b_{Kv} b_{Lv}$, i.e., you have that $A=BB^T$. If you think about this a bit, you'll realize that you don't actually need the connectivity matrix for the whole mesh, but that it is enough if every process (=owner of one partition) knows about its cells *plus one layer of ghost cells*.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth How do you define matrix multiplication with Boolean matrices? If you just consider `True == 1` and `False == 0`, then this multiplication will result in a *dense* symmetric matrix $A$ with values in {0, 1, 2, 3} (for triangular cells), giving the number of common vertices any two cells $K$ and $L$ have. The original cell connectivity matrix (which is sparse) then has 1 in those places where $(BB^{\top})_{ij} = 2$.

Comment: The product on the booleans is just the AND operation. The summation is the OR operation. If you want to work with zeros and ones, then do the inner sum over $v$ and you get a `true` if the sum is non-zero -- just like in C/C++.